# Add DocType to exits DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument, doctype

i have a Php class likes "Extension_DOMDocument" and this extends the PHP "DOMDocument" class.

I create a new Object of Extension_DOMDocument and would add to DocType to this Object.

My code is:

```
// $this->data is an array to convert array to xml 
$objcDom = new Extension_DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
$objcDom->fromMixed($this->data);
```

How I can add an DocType to `$objcDom`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the the DOM implementation to create a document type object. Document type objects are still DOM nodes. You can append them to an existing document.

```
class MyDOMDocument extends DOMDocument {}

$dom = new MyDOMDocument();
$implementation = new DOMImplementation();
$dom->appendChild($implementation->createDocumentType('example'));
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('foo'));

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE example>
<foo/>
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can pass multiple values in the `createDocumentType`, e.g. `createDocumentType('plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"')`

Comment: You're right, but it should be: `$implementation->createDocumentType('plist', '-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN', 'http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd')`. The method adds the `PUBLIC` keyword and the quotes. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would use this

```
 <?php

// Creates an instance of the DOMImplementation class
$imp = new DOMImplementation;

// Creates a DOMDocumentType instance
$dtd = $imp->createDocumentType('graph', '', 'graph.dtd');

// Creates a DOMDocument instance
$dom = $imp->createDocument("", "", $dtd);

// Set other properties
$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$dom->standalone = false;

// Create an empty element
$element = $dom->createElement('graph');

// Append the element
$dom->appendChild($element);

// Retrieve and print the document
echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Check: http://php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocumenttype.php